# How can i validate bulk orders on nft marketplace contract?

Tags: solidity, ether, cryptography

I have a nft marketplace contract. To list nfts i am getting the order details and a signature base on order details. And list the nft on FE. When some user want to buy it i simple sent signature and the nft value. And make the trade. Not so fancy. But now i want to implement a bulk listing feature. When nft holder list the nfts ,let say 10 nfts, i will take only one signature with all 10 detail of orders. But how will i validate this signature when some one buy only 1 of the nft?  When it was only 1 i simple send order details and signature and check the order is valid base on that order details. How can i do it with bulk orders?